Can bad thermal paste cause a PC to not power on at all?
So the other day one of our client's desktops failed to turn on. I would push the power button and the light on the front of the case was on as long as I held the button, but as soon as I let go it turned off. I opened the case and there was no activity other than an unknown green indicator light on the motherboard.
I tired replacing the PSU with one I knew worked, but nothing changed. I eventually took off the OEM cooler and the thermal paste was incredibly old and flaky so I replaced it and the PC turned on without issue.
Does this make sense? I know a CPU can overheat and the PC can shut down, but wouldn't it still turn on and run for a bit, even if just a second or 2?

Is the thermal paste your using electrical conductive? Most are not which means if it were to get on the PCB while it would create a mess it would not damage the components. Verify all cable connections

Just bad thermal paste would not prevent the PC turning on, though it might shut after a time form overheating. More likely you fixed some device that was loose when working on the heat-sink. Still, good work -- it's fixed.

I’m voting to close this question because the core issue is resolved so any remaining questions are theoretical.

For future troubleshooting I just wanted to know definitively that bad thermal paste alone couldn't stop a PC from powering on it seems in cannot. I appreciate your answers!

A CPU is a complex electronics component. ANY similar component may degrade from running hot, this often creates permanent damage. So proper cooling is essential for elongated lifetime as heat comes into the equation.
